# Convert string to hashes and output in json format in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string object which is returned from the controller like below.

```
details = "{"name"=>"David", "age"=>"12", "emp_id"=>"E009", "exp"=>"10",
"company"=>"Starlink"}"
```

So the details.class would be String.
I need to convert it as Hash and output in Json format.So the output would be in below
format. I know that using eval method it can be done. But I think there will be security issues for it. So please suggest the best way to do it.

```
{
  "name":"David",
  "age":"12",
  "emp_id":"E009",
  "exp":"10",
  "company":"Starlink"
}
```

How do I achieve it. Please help

Comment: You are right that eval is way too dangerous. It's parsing time. Regex to get all matches inside double quotes, and then treat them as pairs

Comment: Does it return `details = "{"name"=>"David", "age"=>"12", "emp_id"=>"E009", "exp"=>"10",
"company"=>"Starlink"}"` or `details = '{"name"=>"David", "age"=>"12", "emp_id"=>"E009", "exp"=>"10",
"company"=>"Starlink"}'` because first one causes **syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should go to your API vendor, and tell him he has a bug, since `Hash.inspect` is not a valid serialization, as it is not standard, and may not always be reversible.

If what you get is in the form above though, you can treat it as a JSON after running `gsub` on it:

```
formatted_details = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(details.gsub('=>', ':')))
puts formatted_details
# => {
       "name": "David",
       "age": "12",
       "emp_id": "E009",
       "exp": "10",
       "company": "Starlink"
     }
```

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - you mean values don't have `'=>'` in them... I can live with that...

Comment: Hmmm looks like I misread the question a tad, unlikely to have =>, though possible. Regex something like /"(.*)":"(.*)"/ would have been my first try